# Concurrent code without waiting

Tags: c++, multithreading, concurrency

I'm thinking about a certain kind of synchronisation primitive, but I don't know what this kind of synchronisation is called or if something like this would be working.

So there is one variable (boolean) which basically signals if one thread is still working on a block of memory or not. At the beginning the bool is set to `false`, meaning the worker thread is not working on your block of memory. Now the main thread gives the worker thread a "todo-list", describing how it should be working on that block of memory. After that, it changes the state of the boolean to `true`, so that the worker thread knows it is now allowed to do its work. The main thread can now continue its own work and checks at certain locations if the worker thread is now done working, e.g. if the boolean has been set to `false` again. If it is stil `true`, the main thread just continues its own work and doesn't wait for the worker thread. If the boolean is `false`, the main thread knows the worker thread is done and starts processing the block of memory.

So the boolean just transfers the ownership over a block of memory between two threads. If one thread currently does not have the ownership of that memory, it just continues with its own work, and checks repeatedly if it now has the ownership again. This way, none of the threads is waiting for one another and can continue its own work.

What is this called and how is such a behavior implemented?

EDIT: Basically it's a mutex. But instead of waiting for the mutex to be unlocked again, it continues/skips the critical code.

Comment: This might be a good case for `std::future` and / or `std::packaged_task`.

Comment: Doing one's work while checking periodically for some external events is called "polling". It can be implemented with an atomic variable. It is normally not a good idea.

Comment: Can you explain why?

Comment: Because you waste resources when you poll to often, and wait unnecessarily when you don't poll often enough. Prefer *waiting* for events over *checking* for events, because waiting has none of these drawbacks.

Answer (score 1):

> EDIT: Basically it's a mutex. But instead of waiting for the mutex to
>   be unlocked again, it continues/skips the critical code.

It's still a mutex, just with "try" methods.

in standard C++, we're talking about `std::mutex::try_lock` , which tries to lock the mutex, if it fails it returns false and moves on

```
class unlocker{
 std::mutex& m_Parent;

public : 

unlocker(std::mutex& parent) : m_Parent(parent){}
~unlocker() {m_Parent.unlock(); }

};

std::mutex mtx;
if (mtx.try_lock()){
   unlocker unlock(mtx); // no, you can't use std::lock_guard/unique_lock here
   //success, mtx is free
} else{
  // do something else
}
```

on Native OS's code you have similar  functions depending on the operating system you are on, like `pthread_mutex_trylock` on Unix and `TryEnterCriticalSection` on Windows. needless to say that standard mutex  probably does use these functions behind the scenes

Comment: Is this a valid approach? I need to ask - in concurrent programming, apporaches that seem simple are most of the time wrong.

Comment: If it's the right thing to do = that depends on the application. usually, a much better choice is to decrease contention in general or switch to lock-free data type in the first place. but anyway, you seem to be troubled with performance. I think that one should prove first that contention is his bottleneck

Comment: The problem with `try_lock` is that it is not reliable. Mutex works well for protecting resources from concurrent access, but it does a rather lousy job at signalling. In the C++ threading library if you want signalling, you probably want either future (for one-off signals) or condition_variable (for reusable signals).

Comment: @DavidHaim you can use `std::unique_lock` with the **`std::adopt_lock`** tag. `std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mtx, std::adopt_lock);` An even better approach is to use **`std::try_to_lock`** tag: `if (auto l = std::unique_lock<std::mutex>(mtx, std::try_to_lock)) { ... }`

Answer (score 0):

What will you do if the main thread runs out of work?

Suppose you keep checking and you keep reading `true`. Eventually you reach a point where the main thread cannot continue without the result from the worker thread. Since you have no more work to do, the only thing left is now keep checking the value of the flag over and over, wasting CPU resources that other threads could use to do useful work.

In general, this is not what you want. Instead, you would like the operating system to put your main thread to sleep and only wake it up once the worker thread has finished processing. All kinds of locks and semaphores that ship with modern operating systems work this way. Underneath there is some flag in memory that indicates who owns the lock, but there is also a bunch of logic around it that ensure the operating system won't schedule threads that have nothing to do but wait for a lock to become ready.

That being said, there are some situations where this is not what you want. If you are sufficiently sure that you won't run into the situation where one thread just spins on a lock, and you want to save the overhead that comes with the OS locks, just checking a flag like you described *might* be a viable option.

Note though that low-level stuff like this should be reserved for special circumstances, not be the first tool in your toolbox. It's just too easy to end up with an algorithm that is incorrect or an implementation that is not as efficient as you thought. If you decide to go down this road, be prepared to do some serious work to get it working as expected.